# .h missing when transferred data from view to controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

## View - viewPracticeCode.php

When I am passing

`#include <stdio.h>int main(){printf("Welcome to GLB Coding Club");return 0;}`

through `ajax` to following controller

## Controller - cntrlPractice.php

```
print_r($this->input->post("script",true));
```

giving

`#include <stdio>int main(){printf("Welcome to GLB Coding Club");return 0;}`

that is breaking my code execution. Actually `.h` is missing from `stdio.h`.

Comment: if `<stdio.h>` is replaced by `"stdio.h"` everything woks fine.

Comment: My guess would be that Security class' `xss_clean()` method should be overwritten by custom one. What is result if you don't pass `true` parameter?

Comment: I my `config.php` I have given `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` and elsewhere have not used `xss_clean()` method.

Comment: If I set `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;`, nothing changers with `$response`